# Convert.ToDouble("4089.90") outputs 40.899,00 why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a software that uses number precision, but I have this problem, it happens that when I take a string to convert to double it outputs me with a different culture.

For example I use

```
Convert.ToDouble("4089.90"); // it outputs 40.899,00
```

Is strange cause in my computer it works OK but on the client's PC (with the same culture in regional settings) shows me the latter output. I know I can fix it using

```
Convert.ToDouble("4089.90", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But there is a lot of code in the program using "Convert.ToDouble" and I wouldn't like to change all of it, on the other hand I want to understand why this happens.

Comment: What OS, etc. for both computers?

Comment: Mine is Windows Vista and client machines are XP.

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of all the other answers, so I'm not posting as my own. But if providing `InvariantCulture` to the `Convert` method fixes the problem, it is clearly a problem involving cultures. You should add logging to your program that outputs culture information, and ask for that log from the user(s) reporting the problem. Then you can come back to them and say, "it's because you have these settings on your computer: *blah blah*".

Comment: @jdmichal And if two programs need things set differently to function properly?  It's better just to write the program properly and not force the user to change their computer to suit the program.

Comment: I didn't say, "So you need to change it to this!" I simply said, it would reveal the problem, so that you can tell them what it is. You read the rest yourself. How it would *actually* go, is that you would then give them the cost estimate to fix your program. They'll then change it by themselves without you having to ask! (And yes, I am being facetious.)

Comment: hahaha, gotcha.  Gotta say, though, that most users I've met don't really care about the "Why".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the culture for your thread with:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Comment: +1, as this solves the problem, "But there is a lot of code in the program using "Convert.ToDouble" and I wouldn't like to change all of it."

Comment: As I stated "there is a lot of code in the program using "Convert.ToDouble" and I wouldn't like to change all of it". Thnx jdmichael.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say where you are based, but the output is consistent with the current culture being one that has "." as the thousands separator and a decimal comma rather than a decimal point.

However, you state that the culture is the same - which contradicts this. Have you or the client changed (or customised) the "Standards and formats" on the Regional and Language Options? If the setting has been customised it will still read as "English (United Kingdom)" (or where ever) but will produce different results to the default.

Comment: My culture settings shows comma for thousands separator and dot for decimal. My PC works fine rather than client that uses an OS different from mine (Vista for me, XP for client) that shows another output.

Comment: @nmiranda - in that case the client must have changed their settings along the lines I describe.

Comment: Anecdote: I've had problems similar to this before. I like the (old) German time format of 24 hours separated by a dot. The program parsing my HTTPS security certificate did not :) So it is not sufficient to simply examine the culture name; the devil is in the details.

Comment: +1 for solving the problem, "I want to understand why this happens".

Answer (score 1):

I know neither c# nor asp.net, but I think the problem is this: You are performing the operation in a culture where the dot `.` is the thousands separator and not the decimal separator. The very output you quote is the proof: `40.899,00`.

What culture/locale are you working in?

Comment: My culture setting is from Honduras where separator for thousand is comma and the decimal is a dot. The rare thing as I quoted is that the client machines use the same culture setting.

Comment: But if the culture setting is Honduran, how can the output be 40.899,00?

Comment: That is my question, I've been looking for in the web and the msdn says "Because of differences in precision, the return value may not be exactly equal to value, and for values of value that are less than Double..::.Epsilon, the return value may also differ depending on processor architecture". What can I say I'm confused.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your problem.  See my answer.

Comment: That comment in MSDN has nothing to do with this. That comment is basically saying that the decimal to binary conversion is not always exact and can be off by a very, very small amount. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating%5Fpoint#Accuracy%5Fproblems

Answer (score 0):

Culture could be based on where the ASP.Net application is running, and not the client PC that is running the browser. While their desktop PC might have similar culture settings, the server may differ.

Comment: The server has the same culture settings.

Answer (score 0):

It is your computer that is not giving the correct answer, not theirs.  Your culture states that "4089.90" is the same as 4089900, since the dot (.) is used for separating thousands (and thus there should be three numbers after the dot).

It appears you want to use the dot as a decimal-separator, contrary to your culture settings; so you **have** to use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in your program.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Actually is very rare this behaviour cause all the machines have the same culture settings, however I think that the best solution would be to modify the web.config like this:

```
configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture = "es-HN" />
  </system.web>
</configuration
```

And apply the settings for the entire application.

Thanx everyone for your assistance.